# Getting more precise location information on a PC app with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geolocation

Is there a way to get a more precise location for a unity desktop application? Maybe using ip address or router?

Right now my solution is using the ip address (the freegeoip.net API detects my ip) which basically gives me the country I'm in but not my city or even more precise which is what I want.

This is the code I'm using

```
IEnumerator GetLocation()
{
    // Start a download of position information
    var www = new WWW("freegeoip.net/json");

    // Wait for download to complete
    while (!www.isDone)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    print(www.text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get a more precise location for a unity desktop
>   application? Maybe using ip address or router?

No. I have done this before and I can say that it is good but not precise. I tried multiple API and they all show the-same thing.They show City next to my City. I think that this works by giving the location of the company that assigned the IP Address not the actual location of the router.

It gets the name of the State right each time. So my suggestion is to only use the State. Show the player their State and make them choose their City.